# Modify date format in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am looking to modify this SQL query on a mysql database..

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as TotalValueCount 
    FROM
    wp_rg_lead
    INNER JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail ON
    wp_rg_lead.id=wp_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
    WHERE wp_rg_lead.form_id = '47'
    AND  cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day
    AND field_number = '18'
    GROUP BY value,date_created
```

So that instead of the **'current_date'** format being **'2014-11-12 20:34:12'** it just returns the date instead of displaying the time as well.  I have had a look at the **FORMAT** function but can't see how to apply it in this instance

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the date arithmetic is not doing what you want.  You can try:

```
cast(date_created as date) >= date_sub(current_date, interval 7 day);
```

EDIT:

If you actually want the time component of the current date/time, then use `now()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
cast(date_created as date) >= date_sub(now(), interval 7 day);
```

Comment: I was thinking the same way but it seems the above syntax is valid.

Comment: is there a version of now() that will return the date component instead?

Comment: @fightstarr20 . . . `CURRENT_DATE` returns the date component.  But, in some strange peculiarity of MySQL, these are returned as either strings or numbers, but not dates.  This sometimes causes arithmetic on them to return unusual values, which is way `date_sub()` and `date_add()` are recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap current_date in a date() function:

I.e. date(current_date) and this will extract the date out of any date time and do your calculation on this.

Comment: Misread the question after reading Gordon's answer.. Ignore this :)

Answer (score 0):

you're selecting every column (*) with default given column name my friend. You need to specify the column if you want to change the output format of a particular column.

Here is the Syntax to achieve this:

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt,**'%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s')** AS `Date` FROM **myTableName;**

So, instead of selecting *, put column name(s) and specify the format that you're asking for, i.e.:

```
SELECT column1, DATE_FORMAT(**date_column**,'%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s') AS `Date` , 
COUNT(*) as TotalValueCount
    FROM
    wp_rg_lead
    INNER JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail ON
    wp_rg_lead.id=wp_rg_lead_detail.lead_id
    WHERE wp_rg_lead.form_id = '47'
    AND  cast(date_created as date) >= current_date - interval '7' day
    AND field_number = '18'
    GROUP BY value,date_created
```

Hope that helps!